# How to hide an apex:outputLabel along with the apex:inputField it's associated with

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, rendered, label

Given the code:

```
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.CustomObject__c.Fields.CustomField__c.Label} :" />
          <apex:inputfield value="{!CustomObject__c.CustomField__c}" onchange="updated_fields();"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

This is what I normally see (as expected):

[image: field and label shows up]

But if the viewing user doesn't have field-level security access to the field, they see this:

[image: only field is hidden]

Any way to conditionally automatically hide the label (or other elements) whenever the field is hidden?

Comment: is omitting the outputLabel an option for you?  `inputField` by itself will render the label + valuebox

Comment: @cropredy thanks for your input.  inputField would render the label & value only if it's in a pageBlockSection, not the pageBlockSectionItem, apparently.
Since I'm modifying a page that didn't even use pageBlocks to begin with, and has very particualr formatting, using a separate outputLabel is ideal.

Comment: A controller property can tell you if the field is accessible.